# Find number of occurrence of letters in string

Tags: php, regex

Count number of letters occurrence in string and output as human readable string 
e.g `“aadbbbcddddd”` to `“2ad3bc5d”`?

Comment: Is there a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did it in javascript syntax You can easily convert the syntax in php, not using RegEx

```
var str = 'aadbbbcddddkkkkkffffff'
var res = '';
var howMany = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] == str[i+1]) {
    howMany++;
  } else {
    res += (howMany > 1) ? howMany+str[i] : str[i];
    howMany = 1;
  }
}
console.log(res); //2ad3bc4d5k6f
```

Comment: its great idea , i have changed it into php thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use preg_replace_callback function.

```
$s = "aadbbbcddddd";
$out = preg_replace_callback(
    '~(.)\1+~',
    function($m) {

        return strlen($m[0]).$m[1];
    },
    $s);
echo $out . "\n";
```

Output:

```
2ad3bc5d
```

`(.)` captures a character `\1+` and the same captured character must be repeated one or more times. So this would match all the repeated characters and captures only the first character of repeated character.

Comment: Thank u it give me a solution , but ~(.)\1+~' how it works ?